# How do I remove the Initialization Action in a for-loop, or is it necessary?

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, random

I have wondered about this for some time and when declaring multiple for statements (before I get into turning it into a function) I wanted to know if it was possible to remove of the beginning Initialization Action in a for-loop.

SYNTAX:

```
(Initialization_Action; Boolean Expression; Update_Action)
```

e.x.

```
int main()
{
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<> dis1(1,28440); // Died under 1 year of age.             
    //1.161756638 % chance
    //REFERENCE: http://www.disastercenter.com/cdc/Death%20rates%202005.html

    int count = 0;


    for (int potato = 4; count < 2 && count > -1; count++)
    {
        if (dis1(gen) > 0 && dis1(gen) < 330)
        {

            EndScreen();
            cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t  ";
            return 0;
        }

        else
        {
            Sleep(360);
            cout << "\t\t\tIt's your birthday, you turned: " << count << "\n";
        }
    }
```

Now when I have many multiples of this statement (once again, before I get into functions)
Is there a simpler way than having to put in a placeholder?

In this case,

```
for(int potato = 4;)
```

Comment: Just leave it empty, but don't leave out the semicolon: `for ( ; count < 2 && count > -1; count++)`.

Comment: Have you tried what happense when you leave it empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any of the three parts of a `for` introduction may be empty.

That is, you can write:

```
for (; count < 2 && count > -1; count++) {
```

I would caution you against writing a loop to terminate when a signed integer wraps around to a negative number, though, since it is not guaranteed that it will do anything of the kind; by allowing `count` to potentially overflow, your program will have *undefined behaviour* if the random number generation misses often enough. Mind you, in *this* program, hitting that condition does seem unlikely.

Answer (score 4):

As a matter of fact, *all* statements in a for loop are optional. For example:

```
for (;;) // infinite loop
```

You can simply leave off the first statement if it is of no use to you.

Comment: Minor quip: the first is a declaration, the second an expression in boolean context and the third part would be a statement (or an expression in void context)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply omit *any* section in the `for` construct, you may even write

```
for(;;) {} // infinite loop
```

More information [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for).